# How to manage repeated requests on a cached server while the result arrives

Tags: go, caching, concurrency, redis

In the context of a highly requested web service written in `go` language, I am considering to cache some computations. For that, I am thinking to use Redis.

My application is susceptible to receiving an avalanche of requests containing the same payload that triggers a costly computation. So a cache would reward and allow to compute once.

Consider the following figure extracted from [here](https://www.ingsoftware.com/scaling-with-redis)
[image: Example caching a book]
I use this figure because I think it helps me illustrate the problem. The figure considers the general two cases: the book is in the cache, or this one is not in. However, the figure does not consider the transitory case when a book is being retrieved from the database and other "get-same-book" requests arrive. In this case, I would like to queue the repeated requests temporarily until the book is retrieved. Next, once the book has already arrived, the queued requests are replied with the result which would remain in the cache for fast retrieving of future requests.

So my question asks for approaches for implementing this requirement. I'm considering to use a kind of table on the server (repository) that writes the status of a query database (computing, ready), but this seems a little complicated, because I would need to handle some race conditions.

So I would like to know if anyone knows this pattern or if Redis itself implements it in some way (I have not found it in my consultations, but I suspect that using a Redis lock would be possible)

Comment: Are you running a single instance of the Go server or multiple instances of the Go server?  If it's a single instance, then a pure Go solution may be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Currently, I'm running one, but just for scaling reasons, I should be prepared for running several. I agree with you; it is easier and probably more efficient to solve it inside the server. But I should use an explicit caching service

Comment: Welcome to one of the Hard Problems of software engineering. A Redis lock would likely be fine for a distributed solution, or if it's single-process, you could use a map of mutexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can design it as you have described. But there is some things that are important.

**Use a unique key**

Use an **unique** key for each *book*, and if the book is ever changed, that key should also change. This design makes your *step (6)* save the book in Redis an **idempotent operation** (you can do it many times with the same result). So you will avoid any race condition with "get-same-book".

**Idempotent requests OR asynchronous messages**

> I would like to queue the repeated requests temporarily until the book is retrieved. Next, once the book has already arrived, the queued requests are replied with the result

I would not recommend to *queue requests* as you describe it. If the request is a cache-miss, let it retrieve it from the database - but design it *idempotent*. Alternatively, you should handle **all requests** as asynchronous, and use a message queue e.g. [nats](https://nats.io/), RabbitMQ or something, but the complexity grows with that solution.

**Serializing requests**

> My problem is that while that second of computation where the result is not still gotten, too many repeated requests can arrive and due to the cost I need to avoid to repeat their computations. I need to find a way of retaining them while the result of the first request arrives.

It sounds like you want to have your computations **serialized** instead of doing them concurrently because you want to avoid doing the same computation twice. To solve this, you should let the requests **initialize** the computation, e.g. by putting the input on a **queue** and then do the computation in a serial order (but still possibly concurrently if they have a different *key*) and finally notify the client, or if the client is subscribing for updates (a better solution).

Redis do have support for [PubSub](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub) but it depends on what requirements you have on the clients. I would recommend a solution without locks, for scalability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My operations are stateless, so idempotent too. I agree with the asynchronous nature you pose. The operations are very costly. My problem is that while that second of computation where the result is not still gotten, too many repeated requests can arrive and due to the cost I need to avoid to repeat their computations. I need to find a way of retaining them while the result of the first request arrives. I do not believe that I am the first person finding this problem. I wonder if Redis itself does not offer a direct solution or some helper for achieving it.

Comment: I think the last part is debatable. If there is an upstream cost (i.e. if the problem isn't just waiting on the client side, but load incurred on the data source), it could be a vastly superior solution to hold concurrent requests until it can be retrieved a single time, then let all the concurrent requests serve the newly-cached result.